# Angular json marshalling via $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am having a very weird problem.  Using $http my response is not getting marshalled correctly into map/object. The data is a map of lists.  The issue is that the element 100110150000000751 has a value from the raw data in the first log "1 group data[".  but after its converted to json it has the value of an empty array.  You can see the image of the "after conversion" log.  This all works fine in chrome with debugger open but not if debugger is closed.  The method is so simple and there is little to no room for race conditions or anything.  I created a little desktop html file with all the same libraries and just calling a function without $http and it works without issue.  Angular 1.4.5   Any help is much appreciated.

```
transformResponse: function(groupMapResponse){
   console.log("1 group data ["+groupMapResponse+"]");
   var asdfdsafsad = (typeof groupMapResponse === 'string')?JSON.parse(groupMapResponse):groupMapResponse;
   console.log("after conversion:",asdfdsafsad);
   return asdfdsafsad;
}
```

The console log is:

1 group data [{"1000110150000002801":["1000110020000007753"],"1000110150000002855":["1000110020000009470"],"1000110150000004452":["1000110020000007895"],"1000110150000004362":["1000110020000006355"],"1000110150000004361":["1000110020000010309"],"1000110150000000751":["1000110020000007950"],"1000110150000004412":["1000110020000006353"]}]

[image]

Comment: So where is it **not** working?

Comment: Um the field ending with 751 should not be an empty array

Comment: In concatenating `groupMapResponse` in the console output, you're implicitly converting it to a string where it might not be. You should use something like `console.log('typeof groupMapResponse', typeof groupMapResponse); console.log('groupMapResponse', groupMapResponse)` to see what it actually is

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was not in marshalling at all.  The object was already linked to a bound object and was later altered but the log message was updated with the bound value.  Anyway...